# Where we can find ddl script of external table in oracle(any system table)

Tags: oracle, external-tables

I tried with below code but unable to get the DDL script,

```
  SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('TABLE', 'TABLE_NAME', 'OWNER') FROM dual
```

Is there any oracle system table where we can see definition of External table.

Comment: This is the right query and should give you the DDL.

Comment: Check the object in `select * from dba_objects where object_name ='TABLE_NAME';` and pass the value of correct owner

Comment: Thank You .I got the script . There was an grant issue .Thanks for you valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL will work for external tables just fine, eg

```
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','SALES_EXT') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','SALES_EXT')
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "MCDONAC"."SALES_EXT"
   (    "CUST_ID" VARCHAR2(10) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP" NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "AMT" NUMBER,
        "DTE" DATE,
        "AMT10" NUMBER(*,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("AMT"*10) VIRTUAL
   )  DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP"
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY "TEMP"
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( records delimited by newline
    ...
    ...
```

You can also get additional information from xxx_EXTERNAL_TABLES